# cassandra should I need 4 tables for this case?

Tags: cassandra, data-modeling

I have an table named items_by_id like this:

```
items_by_id
    item_id uuid
    name TEXT
    desc TEXT
    price DECIMAL
    category TEXT
    trouser_size INT
    shoe_size INT
    tshirt_size INT
    color TEXT
```

So now I make the item id primary key and clustered name.

If I want to add many filters like colors, or highest price should I need for each filter an table ?

example I want to sort colors:

```
items_by_color
    item_id uuid (NOT PRIMARY KEY)
    name TEXT
    desc TEXT
    price DECIMAL
    category TEXT
    trouser_size INT
    shoe_size INT
    tshirt_size INT
    color TEXT (PRIMARY KEY )
```

and for price a new table and partition key the price. Is that correct or wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use secondary indexes[(link)](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql-oss/3.3/cql/cql_using/useSecondaryIndex.html).Secondary indexes can lead to performance hit so use them judiciously. A general rule of thumb is to index a column with low cardinality of few values. Before creating an index, be aware of when and when not to create an index.

If you want to search by those filters then yes you should have those many tables or you can use secondary index as explained above. I would prefer to have different tables as it make life easier in the long run.

Comment: thanks for your answer. Maybe I insert an item to item_by_id. But then the datas in item_by_color etc are empty. So I have to write an query for all tables or not ?

Comment: Yes, you have to populate data in all the tables you create.

Comment: Is that not expensive if I write 7x Insert querys ?

Comment: That write hit you might have to take for faster reads. I recommend reading https://www.datastax.com/resources/ebook/oreilly-cassandra-definitive-guide. You can also use search platforms  like solr if you want search by filters.